# Must one boil tap water for it to be kosher?

Tags: kashrut-kosher

I have heard different opinions regarding the need to boil (NYC) tap water prior to consumption - for kashrus reasons.

What are the reasons that it would need to be boiled at all?

Comment: you can start reading here https://oukosher.org/blog/consumer-news/nyc-water/ and here https://www.nytimes.com/2004/06/01/nyregion/there-s-something-in-the-water-and-it-may-not-be-strictly-kosher.html

Comment: How would boiling the water help? The creatures, if forbidden, are just as forbidden dead as alive

Comment: @יהושעק boiling might have an effect on whether the creatures are recognizable, and then other halakhic mechanism might kick in causing the water to be permitted (e.g. safeq, bittul, etc.). As for whether boiling actually does have that effect on copepods, I don't know.

Comment: Boiling water is a common misconception when it comes to insects. Some say that blanching that is done to fruit before freezing makes the bugs break apart and are therefore batul. Presumably, that’s where the idea of boiling water comes from as well. Perhaps you heard that hot water doesn’t need to be filtered in NYC? That’s because it’s assumed that you’re not drinking it. https://checkvegetables.com/new-york-city-water/

Comment: Copepods are (mostly) invisible to the naked eye, and if one does see them he sees white specks. These white specks, if visible at all, are still the same after boiling. As for bittul, there is actually *less* water after boiling than before. Filtering makes sense, but I can't see how boiling would make a difference at all

Comment: @יהושעק the theory is that they lose the berya status since a piece falls off, and now bittul kicks in. The reason why they are not batul is because of berya.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you @Chatzkel, it at least makes some sense to me now